# Generate random numbers equaly in group

Tags: excel

Is there any excel function to generate random numbers in groups and to ensure that the numbers will distribute equally?

For example, 
if i have 3 groups (a ,b ,c ) with list of 30 names in each one and i want to assign random numbers from 1-4 for each name in a group and to make sure that each number will be assign exactly (or close) number of times so ill get a distribution of 25% for each number

Thank you

Comment: [Law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers)

Comment: @GalAbra How is that relevant here? Law of large numbers just says that the result of an experiment performed will more closely approach the theoretical expected value as the number of attempts greatly increases. This isn't what this question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with 3 columns. In the first column, generate some random numbers (I placed this in B2):

```
=RAND()
```

In the second column, rank the items from that first column:

```
=RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$16)
```

Lastly, if you use QUOTIENT, it will break them into 4 equal groups:

```
=QUOTIENT(C1,4)+1
```